# gcc error undefined symbol compiling perl 5.22 on aix 7.1

Tags: perl, gcc, aix

Trying to compile perl 5.22.0 on AIX 7.1 with gcc 4.2.0. gcc is from the AIX toolbox shipping with AIX 7.1. I need to build a perl to ship with our product, customer insists on this.

I used following settings for perl's configure, which finished just nice

```
sh Configure -des -Dcc=gcc -Dprefix=/my/own/dir -Duserelocatableinc
```

Then I run make, which exits with the following error:

```
gcc -maix32 -c -DPERL_CORE -D_ALL_SOURCE -D_ANSI_C_SOURCE -D_POSIX_SOURCE -DUSE_NATIVE_DLOPEN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGE_FILES -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -std=c89 -O -Wall -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Wextra -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings caretx.c
        gcc -maix32 -o miniperl -Wl,-brtl -Wl,-bdynamic -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-b32 -Wl,-bmaxdata:0x80000000 perlmini.o opmini.o miniperlmain.o  gv.o toke.o perly.o pad.o regcomp.o dump.o util.o mg.o reentr.o mro_core.o keywords.o hv.o av.o run.o pp_hot.o sv.o pp.o scope.o pp_ctl.o pp_sys.o doop.o doio.o regexec.o utf8.o taint.o deb.o universal.o globals.o perlio.o perlapi.o numeric.o mathoms.o locale.o pp_pack.o pp_sort.o caretx.o   -lpthread -lbind -lnsl -lgdbm -ldbm -ldl -lld -lm -lcrypt -lc
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .__truncl128
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .__copysignl128
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
collect2: ld returned 8 exit status
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.
```

I ran `sh Configure` without the `-des` switch, trying my best to give reasonable answers, but got the same result.

A search for truncl128 and/or copysignl128 yields almost no hits. Seemingly an astrophysicist [patched gcc 4.5 because of that](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2010-08/msg00051.html). I did try to compile gcc 4.5 on my own but there is too much stuff I would need to install for that (e.g. binutils, which I had to compile first, too). RPM binaries of a more up-to-date gcc lead me into dependency hell. So I'm stuck to IBM's toolset.

Coudn't find a hint in Perl's README for other config/compiler options on this issue. Did I overlook something?

The "128" seems to point to the precision of integers/numbers in some math libraries. I don't need that. If there is some "forget super high precision" switch, it would be just fine.

Does anybody have a clue about getting around the compiler error? If possible with AIX's standard tools?

EDIT: Here's the output of -Wl,-bloadmap:loadmap.txt:

```
cat loadmap.txt
(ld): setopt 64
(ld): halt 4
(ld): setopt r/o->w
(ld): setopt nodelcsect
(ld): setopt rtl
(ld): setopt rtllib
(ld): setopt symbolic:1
(ld): setfflag 4
(ld): savename miniperl
(ld): filelist 52 1
(ld): i /lib/crt0_64.o
(ld): i /tmp//ccgIAPwm.o
(ld): setopt autoimp
(ld): i perlmini.o
(ld): i opmini.o
(ld): i miniperlmain.o
(ld): i gv.o
(ld): i toke.o
(ld): i perly.o
(ld): i pad.o
(ld): i regcomp.o
(ld): i dump.o
(ld): i util.o
(ld): i mg.o
(ld): i reentr.o
(ld): i mro_core.o
(ld): i keywords.o
(ld): i hv.o
(ld): i av.o
(ld): i run.o
(ld): i pp_hot.o
(ld): i sv.o
(ld): i pp.o
(ld): i scope.o
(ld): i pp_ctl.o
(ld): i pp_sys.o
(ld): i doop.o
(ld): i doio.o
(ld): i regexec.o
(ld): i utf8.o
(ld): i taint.o
(ld): i deb.o
(ld): i universal.o
(ld): i globals.o
(ld): i perlio.o
(ld): i perlapi.o
(ld): i numeric.o
(ld): i mathoms.o
(ld): i locale.o
(ld): i pp_pack.o
(ld): i pp_sort.o
(ld): i caretx.o
(ld): lib /usr/lib/libpthread.a
(ld): lib /usr/lib/libbind.a
(ld): lib /usr/lib/libnsl.a
(ld): lib /usr/lib/libdl.a
(ld): lib /usr/lib/libld.a
(ld): lib /usr/lib/libm.a
(ld): lib /usr/lib/libcrypt.a
(ld): lib /usr/lib/libc.a
(ld): i /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/4.2.0/ppc64/libgcc.a
(ld): i /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/4.2.0/ppc64/libgcc_eh.a
(ld): lib /usr/lib/librtl.a
LIBRARY: Shared object libpthread.a[shr_xpg5_64.o]: 342 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libbind.a[shr_64.o]: 412 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libnsl.a[shr_64.o]: 430 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libdl.a[shr_64.o]: 4 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libcrypt.a[shr_64.o]: 8 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libc.a[shr_64.o]: 3075 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libc.a[posix_aio_64.o]: 20 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libc.a[aio_64.o]: 18 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libc.a[pse_64.o]: 8 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libc.a[dl_64.o]: 4 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libc.a[pty_64.o]: 1 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object librtl.a[lazy42_64.o]: 3 symbols imported.
FILELIST: Number of previously inserted files processed: 52
(ld): initfini _GLOBAL__FI_miniperl _GLOBAL__FD_miniperl
(ld): resolve
RESOLVE: 3581 of 15669 symbols were kept.
(ld): addgl /usr/lib/glink64.o
ADDGL: Glink code added for 215 symbols.
(ld): er full
ld: 0711-318 ERROR: Undefined symbols were found.
        The following symbols are in error:
 Symbol                    Inpndx  TY CL Source-File(Object-File) OR Import-File{Shared-object}
                              RLD: Address  Section  Rld-type Referencing Symbol
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 .__truncl128              [4]     ER PR numeric.c(numeric.o)
                                   00000524 .text    R_RBR    [64]    .Perl_my_modfl
 .__copysignl128           [6]     ER PR numeric.c(numeric.o)
                                   00000564 .text    R_RBR    [64]    .Perl_my_modfl
ER: The return code is 8.
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't hurt if you do take a loadmap: -Wl,-bloadmap:loadmap.txt

Comment: So the compiler that compiled 'numeric.c' thought there *were* symbols .__truncl128 and .__copysignl128 somewhere...

Comment: @Zsigmond: thanks for your input so far. Used settings from [perlaix](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlaix.html), 64bit, not threaded (most notably `export OBJECT_MODE=64` and `-Duse64bitall`). Wrote `make distclean` before next run, to make sure there is no "numeric.o" around anymore -- same result. So "numeric.c" is compiled by the same compiler (gcc) with the same settings, all aiming at 64bit (at least to my understanding).

Comment: How came you didn't get 'gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qlongdouble' when configuring?

Comment: Actually, this message shows up:You have OBJECT_MODE=64 set in the environment.
This forces a full 64-bit build.  If that is
not what you intended, please terminate this
program, unset it and restart.
Checking if your infinity is working with long doubles...
gcc: unrecognized option '-qlongdouble'
Your infinity is working correctly with long doubles.
But 64bit is just what I want... In config.sh I find `uselongdouble='undef'`

Comment: I used sed to change every occurance of '-qlongdouble' to '' in files Configure and hints/aix.sh

Comment: I don't get it. With updated Configure and hints/aix.sh `numeric.c` compiles, but now the exact error pops up while compiling `caretx.c`. How is this possible? Is there a per file configuration? I don't think so. I double-checked with `grep -R` that -qlongdouble is not present in Configure and aix.sh anymore. And it doesn't show up in other places (well, it did in aix_[34].sh, but I removed those shorthandedly).

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is not really the answer to my question, but I found a workaround, I'm OK with.

The workaround is to **use perl 5.20.3**. Since this version compiles, tests and installs just fine and 5.20 is still maintained, it seems an acceptable solution.

In perl 5.22 the INSTALL file reads:

```
One option for long doubles is that gcc 4.6 and later have a library
called quadmath, which implements the IEEE 754 quadruple precision
(128-bit, 113 bits of mantissa) floating point numbers.  The library
works at least on x86 and ia64 platforms.  It may be part of your gcc
installation, or you may need to install it separately.

With "Configure -Dusequadmath" you can try enabling its use, but note
the compiler dependency, you may need to also add "-Dcc=...".
At C level the type is called C<__float128> (note, not "long double"),
but Perl source knows it as NV.
```

I thought about filing a bug report at perl.org, because I don't use the `-Dusequadmath` switch, neither in Configure, nor in `-Dcc=`. But I (have to) use gcc 4.2, so I will refrain from that.

@Zsigmond: You've pointed me to the right direction. If you write a short answer here, I'll take that as an accepted answer, so you'll get the credits you deserve. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: off: I've made some efforts to automate compilation+installation, but no success... this prompt-the-user method is plain wrong (imho), I wish to be able to specify keyword=value parameters...